# XPath: Select first element with specific attribute

Tags: html, xpath

The XPath `//img[contains(@class, 'check')]/ancestor::tr//span[contains(@class, 'date-display-single')]` works, but the problem I have is there is two `<span>` with that class in each row.

Which results in:

```
[nodeValue] => Friday 7 October 2016
[nodeValue] => Fri 7 Oct 2016
[nodeValue] => Friday 21 October 2016
[nodeValue] => Fri 21 Oct 2016
[nodeValue] => Friday 4 November 2016
[nodeValue] => Fri 4 Nov 2016
```

What I want is the first `<span>`:

```
[nodeValue] => Friday 7 October 2016
[nodeValue] => Friday 21 October 2016
[nodeValue] => Friday 4 November 2016
```

How can I do this?

Edit: HTML

```
<table class="views-table cols-6">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="a" scope="col"></th>
            <th class="a" scope="col"></th>
            <th class="a" scope="col">1</th>
            <th class="a" scope="col">2</th>
            <th class="a" scope="col">3</th>
            <th class="a" scope="col">4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd views-row-first">
            <td class="a"><span class="date-display-single">Friday 7
            October 2016</span></td>
            <td class="a"><span class="date-display-single">Fri 7 Oct
            2016</span></td>
            <td class="a"><img alt="Yes" class="check" src="image.png"
            title="Yes"></td>
            <td class="a"></td>
            <td class="a"></td>
            <td class="a"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="a"><span class="date-display-single">Friday 14
            October 2016</span></td>
            <td class="a"><span class="date-display-single">Fri 14 Oct
            2016</span></td>
            <td class="a"></td>
            <td class="a"><img alt="Yes" class="check" src="image.png"
            title="Yes"></td>
            <td class="a"><img alt="Yes" class="check" src="image.png"
            title="Yes"></td>
            <td class="a"><img alt="Yes" class="check" src="image.png"
            title="Yes"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post a reduced sample of your HTML that exhibits the problem with your XPath.  Thanks.

Comment: Added.123456789

Answer (score 1):

This XPath, based on your original XPath,

```
//img[contains(@class, 'check')]/ancestor::tr/td[1]/span[contains(@class, 'date-display-single')]
```

will select only the stated `span` elements that are in the first `td` within each stated `tr`:

```
<span class="date-display-single">Friday 7
            October 2016</span>
<span class="date-display-single">Friday 14
            October 2016</span>
```

as requested.

Note, however, this shorter XPath will also select the same elements:

```
//tr[.//img[@class='check']]/td[1]/span[@class='date-display-single']
```

This is fine as long as you can assume single-values for `@class` attributes.  If you cannot, your solution has a serious substring problem whose standard solution involves concatenating spaces around the targeted class value:

```
[contains(concat(' ',@class,' '), ' check ')]
```

This technique could be applied to the above XPath for both the `check` and `date-display-single` tests.

Comment: I'm aware I could use `td[n]`, but that could easily stop working if the layout changes slightly so I'd prefer not to do that.

Comment: Then tell me a non-positional criteria that disambiguates what you want from what you don't want, and I'll show you the XPath for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index, e.g.:

```
(your XPath here)[1]
```

Comment: Using `(//img[contains(@class, 'check')]/ancestor::tr//span[contains(@class, 'date-display-single')])[1]`  
gives me: `[nodeValue] => Friday 7 October 2016` only, which is not what I want

Comment: @FlutterShy try this then: `//img[contains(@class, 'check')]/ancestor::tr//span[contains(@class, 'date-display-single')][1]`

Comment: that gives me exactly the same as without `[1]`